# How to fix the error throwing from formGroup as TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am able to bind other values except the 3 input field values in the same formGroup.
It shows error line for the HTML lines where I have added error message through the get function from ts.

**TS**:

```
get detailsInfo() {
    return this.agentbasicInfoForm.controls;
}

this.agentbasicInfoForm = this.FB.group({
    groupCode: this.agentDetailsList.basicInfo.groupAgent,
    agentCode: [this.agentDetailsList.basicInfo.agentCode, Validators.required],
    agencyType: [this.agentDetailsList.basicInfo.agentType, Validators.required],
})
```

**HTML**:

```
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="agencyType" name="agencyType"
    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && detailsInfo.agencyType.errors }"
    (change)="SelectedAgentType($event.target.value)">
    <option value=''>Select Agent Type </option>
    <option *ngFor="let agencyType of detailsSelectDropDown?.AgentType" [value]='agencyType.id'>
        {{agencyType.value}}
    </option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="submitted && detailsInfo.agencyType.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="detailsInfo.agencyType.errors.required">Agency Type is required</div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
getAllDetails() {
    let params = {
      GroupAgent: this.groupCode,
      agentCode: this.agentCode
    }
    this.agentViewDetailsService.getDetailsTabAllData(params).subscribe((res) => {
      this.agentDetailsList = res.result;
      this.initAllForms()
      console.log(this.agentDetailsList,"all details");
    })
  }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwj4or?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image]

Comment: Just try removing **get** i.e. `detailsInfo() { return this.agentbasicInfoForm.controls; }`

Comment: then how will validation error work?

Comment: `detailsInfo()` will be automatically called from your template. I don't believe you have to use a **getter** function. It would be nice if you can reproduce the error in stackblitz.

Comment: ya i will try to reproduce, even though i removed that detailsInfo issue is the same

Comment: Hi i have reproduced the issue here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwj4or?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Arcteezy are you able to reproduce my issue?

Comment: Yeah. Is that the exact implementation of your code?

Comment: yes, i have pasted my code., and the errors are same as i was getting in my browser but i was able to bind few values to html, except first 3 fields all values had binded

Comment: Check this, [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhp8j2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhp8j2)

Comment: Hi, yes in this errors had been resolved and values got binded, what have you done to resolve that?

Comment: @Arcteezy, i been throgh the code but i am not finding difference, not getting what has been changed, and if possible please have a look at this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59874834/on-click-of-edit-button-in-a-table-how-to-bind-that-particular-value-to-the-for

Comment: You didn't declare `agentDetailsList` properly. Instead of `agentDetailsList = {"basicInfo...}`, you wrote `agentDetailsList : {"basicInfo...}`

Comment: Thanks, so In property declaration also I must give this as public agentDetails ={}?? Or agentDetailsList:any

Comment: I will provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the

> Cannot read property of undefined errors

are caused due to improper initialization of variables.

```
temp : {a:any};
```

This declares a variable with specific types but does not intialize with any value. You have to initialize it separately in `ngOnInit()` or else where before using it in template.

```
temp = {a:"hello"};
```

This declares a variable and intializes it in a single step. I would recommend this only when you don't need to care much on the variable's types. It is always best to set the types first *(That's the whole point of TS :D)* and intialize it later.

In your case,`agentDetailsList : {"basicIn...}` declared the variable with some types which were meant to be it's values instead of initializing it.

Just changing it to `agentDetailsList = {"basicIn...}` solves the problem.

Working piece : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhp8j2

Comment: Hi, this is working fine with your demo but not in my application, May i know what is my problem there?

Comment: except first 3 fields all are getting filled

Comment: i have declared  this.agentDetailsList:any, but not getting why it is throwing error still

Comment: data what i pasted for this.agentDetailsList had been come from backend, so after api hit, im initializing this.agentDetailsList = res.result, where agentDetailsList property has been assigned to any; like this at first, agentDetailsList:any

Comment: Don't do that. Try this `agentDetailsList:any` for declaring. Inside **ngOnInit()**, `this.agentDetails = {"basicIn...}`.

Comment: but that values i am getting after API hit

Comment: So are you calling `this.basicInfoFormInit()` after getting API response?

Comment: yes correct, i have pasted new method now  getAllDetails(), after this api hit, what result i get, that i am passing to the this.basicInfoFormInit(), which is inside initForm()

Comment: All your form fields are fixed right? So you can initialize the form group with some default values in ngOnInit(0. Then after getting API response, update them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206555/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-arcteezy).

Comment: Hi, need your help